# Bootstrap modal not showing with ID > 1000

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

As the title said, i have a table with hundred of row, i assign a td> tag with a modal but i noticed that the modal did not show up if my id is > 1000. This is how i setup my in data target in td> :

```
<td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-{{data.pk}}">{{data.prk.rekap_user_induk}}</td>
```

and in modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-{{data.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
```

for now I am converting my pk to hex (and it works for now) but i realized that soon my pk will past the 1000 in base 16.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of setup you have going on, but `<td>` is a table cell to be used inside a `<table>` so semantically, you're probably using the wrong HTML tag. Also, what exactly is the id?

Comment: @Studocwho i want the cell value to show a modal to edit onclick, so i create a modal to each id with exact cell value. now i get it done with htmx, i only have one modal container and the form is created in server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Django's [l10n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#l10n) will prettify numbers by using thousand seperators (causing invalid ids and targets. Using `{{data.pk|safe}}` will output your numbers as text without thousand seperators.